# Get variables from query with JOIN

Tags: sql

I'm sure that my problem is very stupid, but I don't know how to get data from query after JOIN, when I have columns with this same name in several tables used in query, ex.:

```
$query="SELECT * FROM `clients` JOIN `devices` ON `clients`.`id`=`devices`.`client_id`";
$devices = $Database->select($query);       
for($i=0; $i<sizeof($devices); $i++)
    {
        // I need to get 'name' from `devices` AND `clients` tables...
    }
```

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use alias for table name and for columns

Example

```
SELECT c.name as clientName, d.name as deviceName 
FROM clients c JOIN devices d ON clients.id=devices.client_id
```

Then in your loop you can get "clientName" and "deviceName"

Answer (score 0):

First of all, it doesn't look like you need to select the whole table to begin with. So:

```
SELECT devices.name, clients.name
FROM clients JOIN devices ON clients.id=devices.client_id
```

Now you just need to access the data, one row at a time from $devices.

Comment: Yep it's true, but after widing the query i'll still have to get 'name' from both tables. Anyway thanks for comment :)